# Choose sleep time to retry request - Python

Tags: python, httpwebrequest

I have a program that makes a `web request`. I protect against an invalid request by doing the following:

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    val = makeRequest()
    if val is None:
        time.sleep(i*5)
    else:
        break
```

**My question:** is this a good way to protect against invalid web requests (i.e. connection error, server error, etc.)? In particular, is my choice of increasing time and 5 seconds good?

Edit: the function makeRequest() returns None upon an exception.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to avoid overwhelming the server?  It doesn't look like you'll be handling invalid requests at all if they raise any kind of exception.

Comment: @DavidSanders the function makeRequest() returns none upon exception.

Comment: It's still not clear why, in your case, it would be correct to wait progressively longer periods before making another request if an error happened.